# Django: Any way to webtest-test password reset, given one-time-only link sent to email?

Tags: django, testing, webtest

Is there any way to webtest-test a reset-password request, given the one-time-only-link-sent-by-email part? I'm writing a tutorial on implementing this, and my goal is to create tests for everything reasonable. Not sure what portions, if any, should be tested.

I'm not stuck on webtest necessarily. Can't do Selenium, but straight unit tests are fine, too.

Comment: Are you using Django's password reset views? If so, you probably shouldn't be wasting time on testing code that is covered in Django's own tests. If you aren't, the Django's tests would be a good place to start: https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/tests/auth_tests/test_views.py

Comment: If you are looking for tests involving emails, you can check https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/testing/tools/#email-services

Comment: Then at least I can test that the forgot-my-password link goes to the request-a-reset form, and that submitting that form goes to the "an email has been sent" page. not sure of the other side, without intercepting that email, but that's a start. Will look at the testing-emails page. Thanks.